# CompilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = false performance issue

Tags: c#, nunit, codedom, system.reflection, razorengine

I am using [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) to parse html templates in an app, and was writing some NUnit tests to profile the performance areas and investigate potential problems. It seems that when specifying `GenerateInMemory = false`, my code is suffering a huge performance hit.

When running each test in NUnit, the total ticks spent in the CompileAssemblyFromDom() method is as follows:

```
GenerateInMemory = false:      354,493,052 ticks
GenerateInMemory = true:     6,669,711,153 ticks
```

This is much more extreme impact than I expect for the added cost of some disk IO. Additionally, it seems this time is not linear with the size of the test. For example, when I ran the test for 200 iterations instead of 1000 (in memory = false), the result was 118M ticks, which normalized to the 1000 test iterations is 591M ticks. This is slightly greater than the corresponding test loading into memory, but still an order of magnitude less than the actual performance when the full size test finally completed (I thought it was hanging, but finished while writing this question).

Is there any reason for this huge impact on performance when saving a large number of dynamic assemblies?

Test code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            string s = "<div>" + i + " some random text blah blah... no code specified</div>";
            parser.GetHtmlFromTemplate(s, i.ToString());

        }

        /*
         * Result:
         *     _codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDom:       354493052 ticks
         */
        /* ... collect timing stats */
```

And the GetHtmlFromTemplate() code:

```
    public string GetHtmlFromTemplate(string template, string templateCacheName)
    {
        if (template == string.Empty) return string.Empty;

        ITemplate templateInstance = templateService.GetTemplate(template, null, templateCacheName);
        return templateInstance.Run(new ExecuteContext());
    }
```

A bunch of irrelevant code happens here, and eventually we get to the problem area, which is where a CodeDomProvider is used to compile the code:

```
            var compileTimer = new Stopwatch();
            compileTimer.Start();
            var compileUnit = GetCodeCompileUnit(context.ClassName, context.TemplateContent, context.Namespaces,
                                                 context.TemplateType, context.ModelType);
            compileTimer.Stop();



            var @params = new CompilerParameters
            {
                GenerateInMemory = InMemory, //in memory is a property of this object, and is set accordingly for each test
                GenerateExecutable = false,
                IncludeDebugInformation = false,
                CompilerOptions = "/target:library /optimize"
            };

            //{...} do some reflection to get the referenced assemblies


            var compileFromDomTimer = new Stopwatch();
            compileFromDomTimer.Start();

            var tuple = Tuple.Create(_codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(@params, compileUnit), someString);
            compileFromDomTimer.Stop();
```

**TLDR:** Performance of the `CompileAssemblyFromDom()` method when saving a small number of assemblies (<200) to disk is worse than loading to memory, but when the number is increased (~500-1000), the performance is orders of magnitude worse? What causes this strange behavior?

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code? What using CodeDOM directly, without Razor?

Comment: @svick: I have not used a profiling tool, but the numbers I gave are the total ticks from the `compileFromDomTimer` in the question. So it appears that just the `_codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(@params, compileUnit)` line is to blame. I didn't think that razor should have anything to do with the speed of this statement.

Comment: @svick, it seems like it _might_ be my computer overheating and cutting back cpu. I am getting similarly delayed behavior on some other, much smaller tests (all using `GenerateInMemory = true` and the fan is going like crazy. I am suspicious of this conclusion though since I would expect the "in memory" test to be similarly slow if this was the case since the only difference between these tests _should_ be disk IO. CPU work should be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this [link](http://www.codemag.com/Article/0211081) in wich the author Rick Strahl says that CodeDomProvider compiler loads compiled assemblies in the Application domain:

> Application domains load assemblies, but they cannot unload them!

This is what MSDN says too: see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerresults.compiledassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

so the problem is that the assemblies are all resident in memory slowing the system.